# jQuery for node TypeError: needs a 'context' argument

Tags: jquery, node.js

I'm trying to deploy my node.js server online. On my machine everything works fine, but when moving the server online and running node I get this error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: needs a 'context' argument.
    at Object.getGlobal (/my/path/CloudServer/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:26:21)
    at Object.createWindow (/my/path/CloudServer/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:308:23)
    at Object.windowAugmentation (/my/path/CloudServer/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:63:24)
    at Object.parentWindow (/my/path/CloudServer/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:605:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/my/path/CloudServer/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:81:15)
    at create (/my/path/CloudServer/node_modules/jquery/node-jquery.js:5:47)
    at /my/path/CloudServer/node_modules/jquery/node-jquery.js:9065:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/my/path/CloudServer/node_modules/jquery/node-jquery.js:9067:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
```

Now, I've been trying to follow the stack trace but I cannot figure out where that error comes from. Since the stack shows for the most part problems in jquery for node then I guess the problem is there. Does anyone know what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it may not be a efficient solution, but after I upgrade to node 0.12 this error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just removing jQuery for node.js from my project. If anyone discovers something feel free to post it here and I'll mark it as correct, if it works.

Comment: "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I bend my leg"... Doctor replies: "Then don't bend your leg".  How is this an answer?  It's a comment maybe, but not an answer.

Comment: Quite some time has passed, but I believe I didn't need jQuery for Node but yet installed it for some reason. By removing it I did not remove any functionality and the code worked again. I think Trotyl is right with his answer.